# Factory with Generics what "where T : new()" means?

Tags: c#, generics

Update : my question is rather why is it usefull IN THE CONTEXT OF FACTORY ?

I stumbled upon this article http://weblogs.asp.net/gmilano/archive/2005/07/29/420980.aspx

```
  public interface IFactory<T>
  {
        T Create();
  }

  public class Factory<T> : IFactory<T> where T : new()
  {
        public T Create()
        {
              return new T();
        }
  }
```

What where T : new() means and why is it usefull IN THE CONTEXT OF FACTORY ?

What would be the syntax to create an instance of some class ?

Comment: You should read the documentation for these type of things. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: ok but my question is rather why is it usefull IN THE CONTEXT OF FACTORY ?

Comment: How else is your factory method supposed to know if there is a parameterless constructor?

Answer (score 3):

`where T : new()` means that the type `T` must have a parameterless public constructor.

Usually you will use it when you want to instantiate a generic type.

Answer (score 2):

[`where T : new()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx) is a constraint which means that type argument `T` must have public parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`T:New()` means that the type that should passed as argument to the generic class should have a public default `parameterless constructor`